# Django: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, nginx, digital-ocean

This is my first time deploying Django website on DigitalOcean and it causes me a lot of problems. I am using one click install, deployed my website from git and changed gunicorn and nginx files, but still it gives me

```
Internal Server Error.
```

Here is the Apache log:

```
2015-05-18 15:24:08 [20726] [ERROR] Error handling request Traceback
   (most recent call last):   File
   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line
   45, in handle
       self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line
   119, in handle_r$
       super(GeventWorker, self).handle_request(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/async.py", line
   93, in handle_requ$
       respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line
   187, in __call__
       self.load_middleware()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line
   45, in load_mid$
       mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py",
   line 31, in import$
       error_prefix, module_path, class_name)) ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a
   "SessionAuth$
```

I can't really understand where the problem is and how to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware):

> **New in Django 1.7.**
>
> Allows a user’s sessions to be invalidated when their password changes. See [Session invalidation on password change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change) for details. This middleware must appear after [**`django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) in [**`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES).

Thus, my guess is that you are not on Django 1.7+, yet you have defined the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

### <= Django 1.6

See the [Sessions Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#enabling-sessions).

> To enable session functionality, do the following:
>
> Edit the **`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`** setting and make sure it contains **`'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`**. The default **settings.py** created by **django-admin.py startproject** has **SessionMiddleware** activated.
>
> If you don’t want to use sessions, you might as well remove the **SessionMiddleware** line from **`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`** and **`'django.contrib.sessions'`** from your **`INSTALLED_APPS`**. It’ll save you a small bit of overhead.